# Some negative property of Riemann curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to consider a question about the following,
suppose $T$ is any symmetric trace-free 2-tensor, what conditions on curvature are sufficient for
$$T^{ij}T^{kl}R_{ikjl}\leq 0\,?$$
My definition of curvature is
$$R(X,Y)=\nabla_Y\nabla_X-\nabla_X\nabla_Y+\nabla_{[X,Y]}$$
$$R_{ikjl}=R(e_i,e_k,e_j,e_l)=\langle R(e_i,e_j)e_k,e_l\rangle $$
Note that when $R_{ikjl}=g_{ij}g_{kl}-g_{il}g_{kj}$, we have $T^{ij}T^{kl}R_{ikjl}=-T^{ij}T_{ij}\leq 0$. Does there exists a more general type of manifold has this negative property?

Comment: Do you mean trace-free?

Comment: Yes. @AnthonyCarapetis

Comment: Maybe have a look at Section 11.2 of [this book](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf). You can write your condition as $\langle R, T \wedge T \rangle \le 0$ ($\wedge$ being the Kulkarni-Nomizu product), which means the set of admissible $R$ is exactly the normal cone to $\{ T \wedge T : T\text{ is symmetric trace-free}\}$ at the origin of the space of algebraic curvature operators. At a glance I'm not sure how to characterize this set nicely, but you might be able to get something useful by studying the irreducible decomposition of $R$ and $T \wedge T$.